# Change the margin-top of a <a> element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and this is just some training stuff. I created a basic layout and I add a navigation bar with some a elements. The problem is that you can't see the full a elements. I tried to change the margin-top property to 0 but nothing changed. How could I solve this problem?

[image]

```
#container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}
#Header{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:20%;
background-color:#FFF1D5;
}

#nav
{   
position:absolute;
top:20%;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:5%;
background-color:#660033;
text-align:center;


}

#nav ul li{
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:25px;
margin-right:25px;
margin-top:0;
}
#nav ul li a{
font-size:25px;
color:white;
position:center;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
}

#leftnav
{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:25%;
width:20%;
height:55%;
background-color:yellow;
}

#body
{
position:absolute;
top:25%;
left:20%;
width:60%;
height:55%;
background-color:silver;
}

#rightnav
{
position:absolute;
top:25%;
right:0;
width:20%;
height:55%;
background-color:yellow;
}

#Footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
height:20%;
width:100%;
background-color:green;
}
```

edit :

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href = "üben_css.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <title> K </title>
</head>

<body>  
    <div id="container">
        <div id="Header"> Das ist der Header </div>

        <div id="nav">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Produkte</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a> </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="body"> Das ist der body </div>

        <div id="leftnav"> Linke Navigation</div>

        <div id="rightnav"> Rechte Navigation</div>

        <div id ="Footer"> Footer</div>
    </div>  

</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well please.

Comment: Avoid using unnecessary `position:absolute;` . Build a lay out with relatives, using margins for offset.

Comment: Are the links the "Home", "Produkt" en "Kontakt" Fields?

Comment: you can apply margin only to block level elements, try setting display:inline-block; to your a tags

Comment: @user3008011 As I said I'm new with CSS and I don't really understand the position property's.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question then:

```
#Header{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:20%; /* This is set to 20%, try increase it */
background-color:#FFF1D5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your elements have the position attribute you can assign them the z-index attribute to control which one goes on top.  Also, I personally wouldn't have that many elements with the position: absolute on there.  It'll be a mess of work if you decide you want to move one of them.  Try assigning some of them with position: relative.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp